# How to output markers from SQLite database to MapView and Google Map

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have set my code out so when the user moves to the map fragment it shows a map with all the markers in the database. I have two dummy markers and they work, but thew ones from my database dont show.

I have made sure the SQL query is correct and have tried adding static markers, but the dynamic ones dont show up.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map,container,false);
    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "onMapReady");
            map = googleMap;
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            LatLng paris = new LatLng(12,-40);
            map.addMarker(new 
            MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            map.addMarker(new 
            MarkerOptions().position(paris).title("Marker in Ocean"));
              try {
                  String sql = "SELECT 
                         marker.markerLat,marker.markerLon,marker.markerDate 
                        FROM marker LEFT JOIN tripMarker ON" +
                         " marker.markerID = tripMarker.markerID LEFT 
                         JOIN userTrip ON userTrip.tripID = 
                         tripMarker.tripID " +
                       "WHERE userTrip.userID = '" + User.UserLoggedOn 
                         + "';";
                  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                  if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                          double lat = 
                       cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("markerLat"));
                          System.out.println(lat);
                          double lon = 
                       cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("markerLon"));
                          System.out.println(lon);
                          LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                          MarkerOptions markerOptions = new 
                          MarkerOptions();
                          markerOptions.position(latLng);                        
                         map.addMarker(markerOptions.title(cursor.getString(
                          cursor.getColumnIndex("markerDate"))));
                      }
                  }
              }catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
    }
```

Here is my fragment XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Did you check if the query returns some result or is returning null. Put log in your if condition and check this if you have data in the database which fulfils the query written above and also put log in catch to make sure nothing is breaking in try block

Comment: @akhilchoudhary for some reason, I have put logs in the if statement and in the catch, but I cant seem to find them. Does that mean they both dont trigger?

Comment: @coder188642 It means that you query is returning null thats why its not entering the if condition. Check you sql query and also make sure that there is some data which matches the condition of the query.

Comment: @akhilchoudhary rawQuery nor query will return a null Cursor. The Cursor may be empty in which case the count method will return 0. Empty Cursors are quite typical and actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be skipping the first row? Is it the only row that would be returned?

Perhaps the reason why logging doesn't work as per the comment :-

> for some reason, I have put logs in the if statement and in the
>   catch, but I cant seem to find them. Does that mean they both dont
>   trigger?

Perhaps you should try (removing the `if (csr.moveToFirst())` which will skip the first row) by using :-

```
          MarkerOptions().position(paris).title("Marker in Ocean"));
          try {
              String sql = "SELECT 
                     marker.markerLat,marker.markerLon,marker.markerDate 
                    FROM marker LEFT JOIN tripMarker ON" +
                     " marker.markerID = tripMarker.markerID LEFT 
                     JOIN userTrip ON userTrip.tripID = 
                     tripMarker.tripID " +
                   "WHERE userTrip.userID = '" + User.UserLoggedOn 
                     + "';";
              Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
              while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                      double lat = 
                  cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("markerLat"));
                  System.out.println(lat);
                  double lon = 
                  cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("markerLon"));
                  System.out.println(lon);
                  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new 
                      MarkerOptions();
                  markerOptions.position(latLng);                        
                  map.addMarker(markerOptions.title(cursor.getString(
                      cursor.getColumnIndex("markerDate"))));
              }
          }catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I would also drop wrapping the code in a try/catch clause you may well be hiding issues.

Comment: Ive done what you said, I think they problem now is the cursor is returning null because there is now a Log in the while loop and it hasnt triggered, I have a look at the SQL query, although im fairly sure its correct

Comment: Cursor will never be null, rawQuery will always return an instantiated Cursor unless it crsahes. Cursor may be empty. You could add Log.d("COUNT",String.valueOf(csr.getCount()) + " rows extracted"); immediately after getting the Cursor.

Comment: Would also be useful to add a breakpoint on the line ` Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);` and then use Run/Debug App (Shift + F9 or little green bug icon instead of green right arrow). When it stops look at the sql variable. Is the WHERE clause sensible i.e is the value in single quotes what you expect a userID to be.

Comment: Could also try to use no WHERE clause e.g. `String sql = "SELECT 
                     marker.markerLat,marker.markerLon,marker.markerDate 
                    FROM marker LEFT JOIN tripMarker ON" +
                     " marker.markerID = tripMarker.markerID LEFT 
                     JOIN userTrip ON userTrip.tripID = 
                     tripMarker.tripID LIMIT 3;";` (limit added so not to many markers show up). If this works then issue is with WHERE clause.

Comment: I think I solved it. My SQL statement was wrong. User.UserLoggedOn returns the users username not ID. It is now working.